# Servlet response in particular part of HTML

Tags: java, html, servlets

I am trying allready more than 2 Days to find out how to place response from Servlet to the particular position of an HTML page. Location should be at the place where "Here I want to be!!!" is

```
<form name="input" action="ExamServlet" method="get">
<table>
  <tr>
   <th>Nr.</th>
   <th>"Here i want to be!!!"</th>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>3+1=4?</td>
 <input type="submit" value="Einreichen">
 </form>
```

The doGet method from servlet is here:

```
        PrintWriter pwritter=response.getWriter();
    pwritter.print("here i am ");
    RequestDispatcher dis=request.getRequestDispatcher("Exam.html");
    dis.include(request, response);
```

And as most of experienced programmers would notice, i am getting the value "here i am " above the html table.

to be more precise with the question:

Is it at all possible what i want by using only servlets and HTML? If yes, small hint would be perfect!
If not, should i use JavaScript? I would prefer without it...

Thanks in Advance!!
Der Kerl

Comment: You can use [EL (Expression Language)](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjddd.html) to accomplish that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try first put in output stream part of html before place where you need input your data:

```
pwritter.print("<form name="input" action="ExamServlet" method="get">" +
"<table>"+
  "<tr>"+
   "<th>Nr.</th>"+
   "<th>");
```

then put there your data:

```
pwritter.print("here i am ");
```

then put what is left from static html.

```
pwritter.print("</th>"+
  "</tr>"+
   "<tr>"+
    "<td>3+1=4?</td>"+
 "<input type="submit" value="Einreichen">"+
 "</form>");
```

and then do `dis.forward(request, response);`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you a different approach. Why not call your servlet by Ajax through javascript. Then catch the response in java script function and then using document.getElementById("someId").innerHtml method to insert the response of servlet.

There would be no page refresh and submits. Just an ajax call to servlet, catch the response and write the response.